# how to run jqplot in a function with variables passed into it

Tags: jquery, function, jqplot

I am trying to create a function that uses jqplot to create a graph.
But I need to wrap it in a function so I can call it dynamically, and run it multiple times.

If I do:

```
graphCreate = function()
{
    $.jqplot(
        'chartDiv',[['2017-01-30 00:00:00',100],['2017:01:30 01:00:00',200],['2017-01-30 00:02:00',300]]
    )
}

graphCreate()
```

then I get (a very basic) graph. But If I try and do:

```
graphCreate = function(divName,dataVals)
{
    $.jqplot(
        '\''+divName+'\','+dataVals
    )
}

graphCreate( 'chartDiv','[[\''2017-01-30 00:00:00\'',100],[\''2017:01:30 01:00:00\'',200],[\''2017-01-30 00:02:00\'',300]]')
```

then I get:

```
"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #'chartDiv',[['2017-01-30 00:00:00',100],['2017:01:30 01:00:00',200],['2017-01-30 00:02:00',300]]"
```

I'm looking to be able to do something like:

```
graphCreate( 'chartDiv1','[[\''2017-01-30 00:00:00\'',100],[\''2017:. . . ]')
graphCreate( 'chartDiv2','[[\''2017-01-29 00:00:00\'',105],[\''2017:. . . ]')
graphCreate( 'chartDiv3','[[\''2017-01-28 00:00:00\'',10],[\''2017:. . . ]')
```

Is there a way to do want I am trying ?